# C# Downloading Salesforce Attachments

Tags: rest-api, c#, httprequest

I am attempting to pull an attachment and serve it up in an API. I am consistently getting a bad request error, And I cannot see to understand why this is not producing the byte stream I am looking for. Can someone take a look and offer insight?

A couple points:
I am validating into SFDC without issue. I have tried to do this through an async query instead and have only gotten a link that does not help.

```
        var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateHttp(Properties.Settings.Default.url3 + documentId + "/body ");
        req.Headers.Add("Authorization: Bearer " + Properties.Settings.Default.token);
        req.Method = "GET";

        WebResponse resp;
        byte[] doc = null;
        String content;

        Console.Write(req);

        resp = req.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
        content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        doc = Convert.FromBase64String(content);

        return doc;
```

Comment: What does `Properties.Settings.Default.url3` look like? Is it correctly set to the serverURL that comes back from the authentication steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad request error is likely caused by having the incorrect pod/instance in the request URL.

Also, you don't need to base64 decode the response. It will be the raw binary form. See [Get Attachment Content from a Record](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_blob_retrieve.htm)

```
        var auth = new AuthenticationClient();
        await auth.UsernamePasswordAsync(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, Username, Password);

        string url = auth.InstanceUrl + "/services/data/"+ auth.ApiVersion + "/sobjects/Attachment/00P7000000rfpYPEAY/body";

        var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
        req.Headers.Add("Authorization: Bearer " + auth.AccessToken);
        req.Method = "GET";

        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        byte[] doc = null;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            resp.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(ms);
            doc = ms.ToArray();
        }

        File.WriteAllBytes("attachment.png", doc);
```